# How is current GMT zone defined in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just cast a `08/23/2012` to date in javascript:

```
var value = '08/23/2012';
var newdate = new Date(value);
```

`newdate` happens to be Date `{Thu Aug 23 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)}`

I live in London (GMT 0:00) so where does the +1 assumption come from and how can I set it right?

Comment: London is GMT+1 right now due to Daylight Savings Time http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country

Comment: BST = British Summer Time: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time

Comment: is it? Oh dear...I am coding too much. Lost the time :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in the `Europe/London` timezone, with is GMT+0100 during the summer, due to the Daylight Saving Time scheme.

This is why it's usually better to configure systems based on the location, and adapt the timezone by looking up the [tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). Unfortunately, JavaScript implementations in browser are quite poor regarding the general handling of time zones.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, your comment below made me think to refactor my model. I am using Django, and utilizing the Timezone support there means the datetimes are stored in UTC in database and adjusted to local user. I have combined my Date and Time into one DateTime field. And Use `now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)` to get time-zone-aware dates in my application. Lets hope this sorts out my date issues :) I will update you guys..

Answer (score 0):

London is currently GMT+1 because of Daylight Savings.

If you want dates unaffected by timezones or DST, you need to do two things:

1. Define dates with a timestamp. A timestamp is a number of milliseconds since the Epoch, and is completely agnostic with regards to timezones and DST
2. Use the `Date.getUTC___()` functions to get the date and time in UTC, which is basically GMT but without the daylight savings.

Comment: Very nice. How do I turn a date into a timestamp?

Comment: Use [`Date.getMilliseconds()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds). This should work OK as long as the timezone you're in now was the same as the timezone when the timestamp since epoch was: this causes problems for regions that have changed their timezones over the years (not just DST).

Comment: Just a headsup regarding your method nr 2. I did this method: `function convertDateTimeToUTC(date) { 
 return new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds()); 
 }` and it produces this date. `Date {Wed Aug 22 2012 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)}`  Do you see 23 August 00:00 has become 22 August 11:00 PM. I think its because its neglecting the day time saving. But causes issues with dates now. If I wanted to fetch only yyymmdd, I am a day behind...

Comment: @Kave, you're hitting the general design issues with `Date`, which isn't actually a class to model dates, but rather date+times (the Java `Date` class has the same problem). It's not clear what you're trying to do, but in general, if you want a piece of information to mean that it's a date, keep it as such (e.g. '2012-08-23', although here your other problem is that you're using a US locale whereas you seem to be in the UK) until you really need to process it as a `Date`, if you ever need.

Comment: First create a date, then either call `setTime()` on it with a timestamp, or use the `setUTC____()` methods for each element of the date. You can then use the `getUTC___()` methods to get that date back. Usually, I have the server provide the timestamp in UTC, and use that as a basis for calculations.